# Write Windows CMD output to log file?

Tags: cmd

I query a "never ending stream" with the CMD of Windows.

```
curl --user username:password http://example.com/preview.json
```

How do I get the output to be written to a log file but also displayed in the CMD?

Comment: What makes it a "never ending stream?" It sounds like you should use `Invoke-WebRequest` and `Tee-Object` If you are on a supported system with `cmd.exe` then it will have or can have `powershell.exe` 5.1+.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell launch of delprof2 fails. So we had to go batch to batch files for delprof2